# How can I destructure a state array of objects in this react component to use individual field data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have 96 objects in an array in the component's state after a fetch. They are all unique objects except for the year and in some cases the month. The year can not be set statically because it will obviously change at some point. The months will be converted from an `Integer` to a `String`. I have tried to map it but I get an error that says `cannot read property map of undefined`. However, if I `console.log` the data, it I will get the array with 96 objects. And when I try to destructure it I get an error `Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance`. **My Main Goal is to take the year and pass it as a template literal to the `headerName` so that it loads as a grouped column for all the data below. And to take the month integer and convert it into a string of that month** My code for this component is below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";

class ColumnGroups extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: "Year",
          field: "year",
          children: [
            {
              headerName: "Month",
              field: "month",
              width: 150,
              children: [
                  {
                  headerName: "Sold",
                  field: "sales",
                  width: 150
              },
              {
                  headerName: "Return",
                  field: "returns",
                  width: 150
              },
              {
                  headerName: "RMA%",
                  field: "rma",
                  width: 150
              }
                  ]
              }

              ],
              defaultColDef: {
                  editable: false,
                  sortable: true,
                  resizable: true,
                  filter: true
                },
                rowSelection: "multiple",
                rowGroupPanelShow: "always",
                pivotPanelShow: "always",
                paginationPageSize: 10,
                paginationNumberFormatter: function(params) {
                  return "[" + params.value.toLocaleString() + "]";
                },
                rowData: []


          }

      ],
  }

  }
  onGridReady = params => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const updateData = data => {
      this.setState({ rowData: data });
      params.api.paginationGoToPage(4);
    };

    httpRequest.open(
      "GET",
      "http://localhost:5000/api/salessummary"
    );
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
        updateData(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));
      }
    };
  };

  onPageSizeChanged(newPageSize) {
    var value = document.getElementById("page-size").value;
    this.gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(Number(value));
  }

render() {
  {console.log(this.state.rowData)}
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div 
    className="ag-theme-balham"
    style={{ 
    height: '500px', 
    width: '100%' }} 
  >
      <div className="test-header">
        Page Size:
        <select onChange={this.onPageSizeChanged.bind(this)} id="page-size">
          <option value="10" selected="">
            10
          </option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
          <option value="500">500</option>
          <option value="1000">1000</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    <AgGridReact
      columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
      rowData={this.state.rowData}
      autoGroupColumnDef={this.state.autoGroupColumnDef}
      defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
      suppressRowClickSelection={true}
      groupSelectsChildren={true}
      debug={true}
      rowSelection={this.state.rowSelection}
      rowGroupPanelShow={this.state.rowGroupPanelShow}
      pivotPanelShow={this.state.pivotPanelShow}
      enableRangeSelection={true}
      pagination={true}
      paginationPageSize={this.state.paginationPageSize}
      paginationNumberFormatter={this.state.paginationNumberFormatter}
      onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
      >

    </AgGridReact>
  </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
}
export default ColumnGroups;
```

here is the part that comes back  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
   <div>
           {
    this.state.rowData.map(data => <div>{data.year}</div> )
  }
</div>
```

The data is as below

```
{
"year": 2019,
"month": 4,
"productStyle": "zzzzz",
"sales": 1,
"returns": 0,
"rma": 0
},
```

Every year is the exact same. Mapping returns 96 years 95 of them I do not need. And it will change I want this to be dynamic to the field year. And I need to have the month accessed so I can change the `integer` to a `string` 3 for April ect.

Comment: `I have tried to map it but I get an error that says cannot read property map of undefined.` - can we see an example of data that fails and the script that maps it?

Comment: Also why not use fetch?

Comment: This data fetch was from the documentation on ag grid. That part is almost irrelevant.

Comment: You're likely trying to iterate over it before it's populated. I'm not seeing where you were attempting to iterate over the array in your example. Am I missing it or was it omitted?

Comment: It was omitted yes. Because I do not really want to map is. I want to choose the year field. Do I have to map it? is that required? because mapping is looping and I do not want 96 years I just want 1

Comment: What is `data` in `updateData = data =>{...}` and are you hitting `onGridReady` if you put a debugger?

Comment: " I have tried to map it but I get an error..." Please show a [mcve] that shows how you tried to do this. The code example should include the `console.log()` call that prints the expected data.

Comment: `{console.log(this.state.rowData)}` is included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in JS method for formatting Month numbers to strings you can build your own:

```
numToMonth(n){
    switch(n){
        case 1:
           return 'Jan'
        //... all months
        default:
           return 'Dec'
        }
}
```

You need to validate before you map. To be extra thorough check that it exists and that its an array:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.rowData && Array.isArray(this.state.rowData)){
        var items = this.state.rowData
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {items && items.map(item => <div>{item.Year}</div> )}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

if you need one item based on the current year use find:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.rowData && Array.isArray(this.state.rowData)){
        var item = this.state.rowData.find(data => data.year === new Date().getFullYear )
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {item && `${item.year} - ${this.numToMonth(item.month)}` }
        </div>
    )
}
```

if you need many items based on the current year filter:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.rowData && Array.isArray(this.state.rowData)){
        var items = this.state.rowData.filter(data => data.year === new Date().getFullYear )
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {item && items.map(items=> <div>{item.year} - {this.numToMonth(item.month)} </div>})
        </div>
    )
}
```

If all have the same year and you need and a bunch of month numbers as strings:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.rowData && Array.isArray(this.state.rowData)){
        var items = this.state.rowData
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {items && items[0].year}
            {items && items.map(item => <div>{this.numToMonth(item.month)}</div> )}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Runable snippet of the last example:

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state={
    rowData:[
      {year:1988,month:1},
      {year:1988,month:3},
      {year:1988,month:2},
      {year:1988,month:1},
    ]
  }
  numToMonth(n){
    switch(n){
        case 1:
           return 'Jan'
        case 2:
           return 'Feb'
        case 3:
           return 'March'
        //... all months
        default:
           return 'Dec'
        }
  }
  render(){
    if(this.state.rowData && Array.isArray(this.state.rowData)){
        var items = this.state.rowData
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {items && items[0].year}
            {items && items.map(item => <div>{this.numToMonth(item.month)}</div> )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This does give back the year. But it loops and gives me 96 years and that is not want I want. I want a single year just one uno.

Comment: @Bama the solution above is to ensure the code doesn't break. You can filter the data based on the year you're looking for, or simply use `find` if you want the looping to stop after you find the one year.

Comment: I keep hearing I can use a filter, but after reading the documentation I can not seem to understand how to implement it correctly care to share?

Comment: im confused by what you expect your desired behavior to be? do you just need the last/first year in the array?

Comment: And Also this is not dynamic, so once the year changes it will always need to be changed in the code. This also does not include the month part of the question.

Comment: Certainly, I am not sure what the data looks like but I'm assuming the objects have a `year` property. You can loop through the data using `filter` or `find` if you want one result. `rowData.find((x)=>return x.year ===  YOUR_YEAR})`

Comment: What year are you looking for? `new Date().getFullYear()` will get you the current year. You can do `rowData.find((x)=>{ var year  = new Date().getFullYear(); return x.year === year})`

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. I am trying to get the year in the field year from my api data

Comment: @Bama please see my answer below. It's dynamic and allows you to change your year should you want to implement any filtering.

Comment: made some edits, let me know if i'm still missing the mark (sorry that my first few edits went wonky btw)

Comment: @Willman.Codes `AgGridReact` gets a prop called `rowData` so there's no need to map over the item(s) and return a `div` for each. You just need to pass the filtered data as an array for `rowData` to the `AgGridReact` component.

Comment: the only problem I am having is a parse error when I test this. Where do the if statements go?

Comment: you should put them above the return but below the render

Comment: okay I was doing it that way. I found two small errors one a missing closing `)` in the if statement of the last part and a missing `/` in the closing `div` of the last part

Comment: and its not based on the current year its base on the year that is inside the year field of the data.

Comment: I updated my answer, check out the last one to see if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: @Willman.Codes Thank you so much you truly put a lot into your answer. I appropriate it. This does help it in a way. And will allow me to accept this answer. Could I reach out to you personally in the future? Via your links on your website?

Comment: Feel free and thanks for asking! Glad we got you one step closer (email is best cheers!)

Answer (score 1):

You can the current year to your state, like so.

```
state = {
   ...
   currentYear: new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

Then you can filter your data by `this.state.currentYear`.

```
var data = this.state.rowData.find((x)=>{return x.year === this.state.currentYear})
```

It appears `rowData` [needs to be an array for `AgGridReact`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-react#set-the-grids-configuration-in-a-parent-component), so write `rowData={[data]}` for `AgGridReact`'s `rowData` prop.

**Edit**

If you're going to be filtering this data in the table based on the year (say you want to look at the previous year's data) add an `onChange` function `changeYear` that will set the state and change the year. See below.

```
changeYear = (year) =>{
    this.setState({
        currentYear: year
    })
}
```

When the state updates, the data will be re-filtered and reflect only data for the newly selected year.

As for the month, you can make the number into a string like so.

```
   formatMonth = (x) =>{
      var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', ..., 'December']
      return months[x-1]
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialised the rowData in your state variable. I see that you have defined rowData inside child of columnDefs in constructor. Here two things are happening.

1. You have initialised **this.state.rowData** inside function **onGridReady**.
2. You are accessing it before it is **initialised**.

So, this.state.rowData is undefined before initialisation and the component is trying to map over undefined. That's why you are getting the error **Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**.

#### Possible solutions :

1. Initialise the variable inside **constructor** before using it . `this.state={... 
   rowData:[] ...}`.
2. Change prop of **AgGridReact** `rowData={this.state.rowData}` to 
   `rowData={Array.isArray(this.state.rowData)? this.state.rowData : []}`

I see there are lot of things you have asked in this question. This is one part of it. Explain in more details what you want or may be divide it into subproblems. Then it would be easy to answer them.